# Resize a window such that the primary widget is a specific size

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application which is essentially a `QMainWindow` which has a menu, a toolbar and a primary widget.

I would like to have a menu item which will resize the application so that the primary widget is a specific size but am yet to figure out a way to do this.

So far, the closest I have come up with is something like this:

```
void on_actionSetSize_triggered() {
    ui_.primary_widget->setMinimumSize(100,200);
    adjustSize();
}
```

The idea being that I set the primary widgets minimum size to the target size, and then ask the UI to "shrink to fit"

Unfortunately, this seems to work sporadically at best, it will certainly increase the size when needed, but when i want a reduction in size, it usually doesn't work :-/.

NOTE: I do want to allow the user to freely resize the application, this is only when they ask.

Answer (score 0):

For the size to also reduce just like while increased you need to set a Fixed Size on your primary widget before calling `adjustSize()`. You can then immediately release the constraint to allow the user to re-size henceforth.

You could try this:

```
ui_.primary_widget->setFixedSize(100, 200);  
adjustSize();
ui_.primary_widget->setMaximumSize(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX, QWIDGETSIZE_MAX);
```

Do note the size your setting on Primary Widget needs to be a valid size based on what's inside it. Else setting Fixed Size on a widget would just pretty much get it to as small as possible without breaking layout constraints and not any further.